# Set environment variable upon application launch

Tags: java, install4j

The application requires an environment variable prior to execution. I was wondering if there is a way to set an environment variable within the launch script itself.

I understand this may be accomplished via an `Action` but I would prefer to set it during run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Unix launcher, you can go to the "Executable info->Unix options" step in the launcher wizard and define the environment variable there.

For Windows, using the "Modify an environment variable on Windows" action is the only option.

For Mac OS X, there is no solution, because it is generally difficult to modify environment variables on Mac OS X.

Comment: As always, thanks for the quick response. It just so happens that OSX doesn't need any changes. So this works out in my favor. Is there any reason in particular that OSX doesn't have the same `Unix options` category? Aren't environment variables treated the same way as they are on Linux?

Comment: You can use the Unix options for Mac OS X, but they are only used for console launchers. There is no stable place where to modify environment variables for all processes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x